# addTooltip with dynamic title

Tags: r, shiny, shinybs

I have a shiny app with an input slider and an output table. I want to put a tooltip over the output table with text that includes the input from the input slider, i.e. the tooltip text updates dynamically with the change in the slider. I cannot get it to work.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)


ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput(inputId="inputValue",label="Input Value", 0,100, value=90, step=1),

  tableOutput(outputId="outputTableId")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  renderTables <- observe({
    browser()
    output$outputTableId<-renderTable({
      data.frame("Output" = c(1,2,3) * input$inputValue)  
    })
    addTooltip(session, id="outputTableId", title=paste0("Tooltip text with dynamic ",input$inputValue,"% prediction interval"), placement="right")

  })


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In my main app (too big to post here), the tooltip was working and updating, but only every other update - on every other change of slider, the tooltip wouldn't show up at all, but the other times it would work, with the correct dynamic value. This may be related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47339183/addtooltip-works-intermittently-with-two-inputs-in-observeevent), which is possibly a bug.

However when trying to create a reproducable example for this question, I cannot even get it to work at all.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, not obvious. Here is the way I've found:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput(inputId="inputValue", label="Input Value", 0,100, value=90, step=1),
  div(
    id = "container",
    style = "display:inline-block",
    uiOutput("table")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$outputTableId <- renderTable({
    data.frame("Output" = c(1,2,3) * input$inputValue)  
  })

  output$table <- renderUI({
    tipify(
      tableOutput(outputId = "outputTableId"),
      title=paste0("Tooltip text with dynamic ", input$inputValue, "% prediction interval"),
      placement = "right",
      options = list(container = "#container"))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```